# How do you read the integers from a text file of both characters and integers?

Tags: c, integer, character

I was having trouble reading and storing the last set of values from a text file. For example, let's say that this is printed in a text file:

ID      Grade
AA22    12
BB33    13
DD44    14

How do I read only the grades of the student and store it in an integer in order to carry out calculations?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlb.h>

FILE *fp;
int counter;

int main () {
    fp = fopen ("nameoffile.txt", "r");
    int line[50];
    while (fgets(line, 50, fp) != EOF) {
       counter = counter + line;
    }
   printf("The total amount is %d", counter);
}
```

It was originally written, and the question asked was similar to the example given. I am really more concerned about the logic.

Comment: "I was having trouble", but I don't see a piece of code that brings the trouble. Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: would you please give your sample code.??

Comment: As WedaPashi said just show us some of your code, even if it's not that good and we will point you to the right directions.

Comment: without having any info we only could take guess at what you need, and I think you need to learn about [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: It is not homework lol. I self study and this question posed a bit of challenge to me. I have uploaded the code

Comment: I see a problem: Where is `line` incremented?

Comment: what is this `int line = [50];` ? Is it valid in `C` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to get you started. You can use this as a base on top of which to build the logic that suits you.

Many error checking must be done, but I left this to you to figure out what needs to be improved.

I suggest you to first analyze it and understand what exactly happens, because there were many fundamentals errors with your code.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("nameoffile.txt", "r");

    char line[200];
    char ids[20][20];
    int grades[20];
    int cnt;

    cnt = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        if(cnt)
            sscanf(line, "%s %d", ids[cnt - 1], &grades[cnt - 1]);

        cnt++;
    }

    printf("ID GRADE\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < cnt - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", ids[i], grades[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that you know how to code but having trouble breaking down the project. Breaking down the project becomes the logic. It's helpful to breakdown the project and then google each point you don't understand. Cause clearly your project is information overload to you. Just try it next time.**

**And sure this is a lot of stuff to do but using this method you'll save a lot of time in the long run. ✔︎**

***Breakdown***

• Read file

• Identify the "Grade" column.

• Read only those values under the "Grade column".

• Make sure the value's characters are all `isdigit()`

• Convert the values to integers:`atoi()` then Add those values to an array for whatever use you want to make of them later. `to carry out calculations` as you said.

**Research Breakdown**

• **Read file**

=> [C Read Text File](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-read-text-file/) ... `Now you have access to each line`

• **Identify the "Grade" column**

=> [multiple spaces to only one](https://github.com/sangeeths/strings/blob/master/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one.c) => `by doing this step, its now easy to identify what your Columns "ID Grade ... ..." are delimited by.`

=> [Find a substring of a string in C](https://www.lemoda.net/c/find-substring/) ... `Now you know you're currently on the line of your HEADERS ... You'll use this headers to figure out what column your grades are under.`

=> By using the `strstr()` example the great internet provided you with, you now have at your disposal the index number of the starting character of the word "Grade".

=> Lucky for you, you already made the column delimiter a single space, so now you loop over the string until you reach that index number.

=> But while doing so, you need to count the amount of spaces you encounter. Because when your loop reaches the index number, you would have the column number of your grades - "Grade", which is actually nothing but the number of spaces.

• **Make sure the value's characters are all digits**

[isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm)

=> loop to the column where your grades value lies... you can do this because you know the column number and the column delimiter.

=> when you reach that point in the string, start checking if each character after that `isdigit()`. by "each character after that" i mean, all characters until you reach a space.

=> if you encountered a character thats something other a digit then throw a little syntax error or something cooler than that. your program!

=> now that you know the grades value is all digits, you want to atoi() that bad boy. but how ? [something like this...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G9tnbILin44ulzpdrVKOUY5tznJQguLb/view?usp=sharing) ...  `this example code is how to get that value out of the whole string. Now you need to take that value in atoi(value).`

=> then you'll add the return value of `atoi(value)` to your values

**Good luck**